# How to resolve the following clang error that I am getting in C++

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++. Following is the code-

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
$ gcc  tut1.cpp -o test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in tut1-4ca6c7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
```

I believe this error has little to do with the code and more to do with how I set up the compiler on my Mac. I am using Visual Studio Code and will not be using Xcode. How can I resolve this error? When I did ls this file in which I have written my code exists in that directory.

I have the following files that already exist in the same space-
Launch.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "clang build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "clang build",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/lldb"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, in a Mac, which command helps in compiling a file?

Comment: This looks like something you'd get by compiling C++ code with `clang` (which is inteded for C). Use `clang++` for C++.

Comment: What is the name of the source code file? Does it end with `.c`? If so, change it to `.cpp` or `.cc`.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_build-helloworldcpp

Comment: Also, cross-site duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675828/gcc-and-clang-cant-compile-c-code

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `gcc tut1.cpp -o test` do

```
g++ tut1.cpp -o test
```

or

```
clang++ tut1.cpp -o test
```

You should use `gcc` or `clang` for `C` programs and `g++` or `clang++` for `C++` programs. Using `g++` and `clang++` makes the compiler add the standard C++ library when linking. If that's not done, you get the kind of linking errors you show in the question.